# @Security("is_granted('remove', user)") uses not request user, symfony2

Tags: symfony, security, symfony-2.8

When I use the annotation `@Security("is_granted('remove', user)")`, I get a wrong user in Voter

```
/**
 * Delete User by ID
 *
 * @Rest\Delete("/{id}", name="delete_user")
 * @Security("is_granted('remove', user)")
 * 
 * @ApiDoc(
 *  section="5. Users",
 *  resource=true,
 *  description="Delete User",
 *  headers={
 *     {
 *      "name"="Authorization: Bearer [ACCESS_TOKEN]",
 *      "description"="Authorization key",
 *      "required"=true
 *     }
 *  },
 *  requirements={
 *      {
 *          "name"="id",
 *          "dataType"="string",
 *          "requirement"="\[a-z\-]+",
 *          "description"="Id of the object to receive"
 *      }
 *  },
 *  output="Status"
 * )
 *
 * @param User $user
 * @return Response;
 */
public function deleteAction(User $user)
{
    //$this->denyAccessUnlessGranted('remove', $user);
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->remove($user);
    $em->flush();

    $view = $this->view('Success deleted', Response::HTTP_NO_CONTENT);
    return $this->handleView($view);
}
```

But, if I use functions in the body `$this->denyAccessUnlessGranted('remove', $user);`, it's all right. Help me to understand...
Settings

```
services:
user.user_voter:
    class: OD\UserBundle\Security\UserVoter
    arguments: ['@security.access.decision_manager']
    public: false
    tags:
        - { name: security.voter }
```

Voter

```
namespace OD\UserBundle\Security;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\Voter\Voter;

use OD\UserBundle\Entity\User;

class UserVoter extends Voter
{
    const VIEW = 'view';
    const EDIT = 'edit';
    const REMOVE = 'remove';

    protected function supports($attribute, $subject)
    {
        # if the attribute isn't one we support, return false
        if (!in_array($attribute, array(self::VIEW, self::EDIT, self::REMOVE))) {
            return false;
        }

        # only vote on Booking objects inside this voter
        if (!$subject instanceof User) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    protected function voteOnAttribute($attribute, $subject, TokenInterface $token)
    {
        $user = $token->getUser();

        if (!$user instanceof User) {
            # the user must be logged in; if not, deny access
            return false;
        }

        switch ($attribute) {
            case self::VIEW:
                return $this->canView($subject, $user);
            case self::EDIT:
                return $this->canEdit($subject, $user);
            case self::REMOVE:
                return $this->canRemove($subject, $user);
        }

        throw new \LogicException('This code should not be reached!');
    }

    private function canView(User $subject, User $user)
    {
        if ($subject->getId() === $user->getId()) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    private function canEdit(User $subject, User $user)
    {
        if ($subject->getId() === $user->getId()) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    private function canRemove(User $subject, User $user)
    {
        if ($subject->getId() === $user->getId()) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
* @Security("is_granted('remove', removingUser)")
* @param User $removingUser
* @return Response;
*/
public function deleteAction(User $removingUser)
```

This code works well. This code works well. I did not find the confirmation, but it seems the user is reserved for the current user